# List comprehension - check for partial string present in a separate list(complete match)?

Tags: python

I am trying to match partials from a list with a complete match in the other list.

```
match_list = ['abc', 'bcc'] # etc

files = os.listdir()

files = ['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc', 'byehelloxyz']

# List comprehension to match partial 'hello-abc'(example) in files with element 'abc' in files.

# this wont work
files = [i for i in files if i in match_list]
# results in files = []
```

Expected output:

```
files = ['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any()`.

```
match_list = ['abc', 'bcc'] # etc
files = ['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc', 'byehelloxyz']
files = [i for i in files if any(m in i for m in match_list)]
print(files) 
# ['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc']
```

Explanation:

```
for i in files: 
    print(i , [[m, (m in i)] for m in match_list])

# hello-abc [['abc', True], ['bcc', False]] -> abc in hello-abc, bcc not in hello-abc
# bye-abc [['abc', True], ['bcc', False]]
# byebyebcc [['abc', False], ['bcc', True]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't even need `any`:

```
match_list = ['abc', 'bcc'] # etc
files = ['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc', 'byehelloxyz']
print([i for i in files if [ m for m in match_list if m in i]])
['hello-abc', 'bye-abc', 'byebyebcc']
```